# HTML5 Required input, removing and adding on the fly not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to remove a required attribute from an input on the fly. The general idea is I have a field that is set to required, this field has custom validation with the pattern attribute. When the user clicks a button I am attempting to remove the required field.

I have put together a fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/paulmatos/t1p1wub3/

HTML:

```
<form>

    <input type="text" oninvalid='this.setCustomValidity("Enter a number in the Specified Range");' oninput="try{setCustomValidity('')}catch(e){}" pattern="[0-9]" required="required" name="password" id="password" />

    <input type="text" required="required" name="temp" />

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control" value="Submit" />

    <div class="btn btn-default removeReq">Remove Required</div>

</form>
```

Jquery:

```
$('.removeReq').click(function() {
  $('#password').removeAttr('required');
});
```

The issue I am experiencing has to do with the order of submission.

If you click remove required, and then submit the form you will see that it works as intended.
However, if you do those steps in reverse order, click submit first, then remove and try and submit again, you will notice I am still getting the validation error on the first input.

Is there anyway to get around this with this intended functionality, I am trying to get this to work just with the html5 validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did have a look at the fiddle and the only way I could get the behaviour you wanted was by literally detaching, cloning and reinserting the field. Works tho.

```
$('.removeReq').click(function() {
  var password = $('#password').removeAttr('required oninvalid oninput pattern').detach().clone();
  $('form').prepend(password);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t1p1wub3/2/

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Think you are getting this due to the code in the oninvalid handler. Try this.

```
$('.removeReq').click(function() {
  $('#password').removeAttr('required oninvalid');
});
```

Comment: unfortunately the problem persisted for me.

Comment: still the same, any fixes ? or maybe workaround ? I need the custom message at the same time the required. But I cannot remove it when it is hidden with "oninvalid"

Answer (score 1):

You can try this instead of removeAtt():

```
$('.removeReq').click(function() {
  $('#password').prop('required', false);
});
```

Comment: unfortunately the problem persisted for me.